# Stm32F4-Discovery starting problem

Tags: stm32, embedded, stm32f4, cmsis

I'm using CoIDE and the CMSIS library. 
The problem is that my programs start up normally only immediately after flashing the board. By disconnecting and reconnecting the board to the usb( just for powering on), the program doesn't start anymore. 
By adding a delay instruction (for loop) in the beginning of the main function, the board works perfectly and programs run normally.

How do I get my program running correctly?

Here is my code :

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_tim.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"


int main(void)
{
    /*SystemInit();
    RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
    while(!RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp());*/
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD,ENABLE);
    for (int i=0;i<0;i++); 
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStr;
    GPIO_InitStr.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_13;
    GPIO_InitStr.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStr.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;
    GPIO_InitStr.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD,&GPIO_InitStr);


    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_13);


}
```

The Led doesn't light up without :

```
for (int i=0;i<0;i++);
```

I was thinking that it was a matter of Time ! : "Something" needs more time to start or so ! :D 
But when i reduced the counter till zero, that was okk too .. the led turned on :D !

Comment: Power On Reset too short? or power on glitches too long?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Are you using a dev board with a built in JTAG or the JTAG through USB

Comment: @Tony: i don't really get your idea.. How can i check or modify theses parameters?!

Comment: @Eugene Sh: a simple blink Led code without any special configuration.. Just i have to add a delay instruction to make the program run normally (for example a for loop: for (int i=0;i<500000;i++);).

Comment: @Laptop2d: sorry for my English and thx for the correction.
The board has a seperate SWD interface.

Comment: The board has a seperate SWD interface.
(see here : https://chippedwood.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/stm32f4-discovery-with-spi-pinout-wiring.png)

Comment: As Eugene said 3 hours ago, you must show your actual code, otherwise this will be closed as unanswerable.  The Discovery board should already have the BOOT0 pin tied appropriately.  You could try doing an explicit reset.  It also has plenty of example code, perhaps you should try that instead of your custom program.

Comment: Done .. But Sorry guys .. Electronics is not really my field. i don't really get your technical words ... what do you mean by "explicit reset" !!
"Power On Reset too short"... "power on glitches too long" !
Try to simplify :D Thx

Comment: No explanation!! :/ I think i could continue learning with that board..  but that issue stick in my mind..  i really want to know what goes wrong and how does it work .. this is too weird!!

Comment: Your code is missing infinite loop. add `while (1) {}` at end of your main. MCU must all time do something. It cant stop at end of main like normal computer application.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but this was not the problem... it's solved anyway, i will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how and why :D but the problem was solved by simply declaring the "GPIO Init Structure" outside the main function.

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStr;
int void main(){...}
```

Comment: No.  This is **not** the solution.  Something else changed which actually solved the problem, either in the code or in your experimental conditions.

Comment: Maybe :D ! forget it ;)

Comment: Your struct was not zeroed. And had rubbish in fields you did not explicitly initialize. Moving it outside main moved it from the stack to BSS which is zero initialized. Try adding `={}` when it's declared in main.